# Regex expression to remove specific characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I'm currently trying to get into regex expressions - at the moment I want to write one which acts as follows:

```
import regex
a = '[[0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1]\n [1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2]\n [2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3]\n [3.4 3.4 3.4 3.4]]'
a_transformed = re.sub(regex_expression, a)

# a_transformed = '0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 3.4 3.4 3.4 3.4'
```

Basically I only need to sub all occurences of (,n,[,]), but currently I'm struggling to get the expression right.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d. ]', '', a)
'0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 2.3 2.3 2.3 2.3 3.4 3.4 3.4 3.4'
```

Here `'[^\d. ]'` means anything except a digit, `'.'` and space like characters. `^` inside `[]` means negate this character group.